# C: Error converting from int to float or double

Tags: c, random, floating-point, type-conversion, int

I'm trying to generate a random number between 1 and 0 for a school project. Several places say this should be done using rand() and casting to float. Something like the following:

```
float x = ((float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX)) * a;
```

However, I discovered that whenever I cast from int to float the number is incorrect. This issue is causing me to get incorrect answers using the code above

Code:

```
int rotlat = rand() % 1000;
double newrot = (double) rotlat;
printf("rotational latency: %d\n", rotlat);
printf("new rotational latency: %d\n", newrot);
```

Output:

```
rotational latency: 533
new rotational latency: -1841876320

rotational latency: 279
new rotational latency: -1841876320

rotational latency: 148
new rotational latency: -1841876320

rotational latency: 167
new rotational latency: -1841876320
```

Comment: 1. Your "something like" isn't at all what you're actually doing in your code.  Why didn't you follow the advice? 2. `%d` is the `printf` format specifier for printing `int`s.  Passing a `double` is undefined behavior.  Use `%f`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
printf("new rotational latency: %g\n", newrot); //%g
```

The `%d` directive is for decimal integers, not doubles.